# GraphQL: How to Prevent Database Scraping?

Tags: graphql, apollo

Let's say I have a graphql endpoint at `https://api.service.com/graphql` that is used to build the company's official UI on `https://www.service.com` + an iOS app + an Android app. I want to expose this API to the public so that third-party apps can build on top of it by querying for data, However I don't want them to be able to scrape my entire database.

Let's say we have a type:

```
type Thing {
  # public fields
  field1: String
  field2: String

  # fields only available in the official UI
  field3: String
  field4: String
}
```

And a query:

```
{
  things(limit: Int!, offset: Int): [Thing]
}
```

What is the best way to only allow the company's official UI to query for all of the `Thing` fields and loop through all things? Third-party devs should only be allowed to query for `field1` and `field2` on each thing, and have some restrictions around how many things they can access.

### Option 1

I thought about requiring every client to include a token in each query request so that the official website, iOS app, and Android apps could be detected and "whitelisted". However, what would stop someone from digging into your javascript / app bundle and finding said token if it is stored on the client?

### Option 2

I thought about publishing two different API endpoints with two different schema / sets of restrictions, e.g.:

`https://api.service.com/graphql` - publicly documented and uses a limited schema.

`https://api.service.com/graphql-anon` - privately used by the official UIs and contains a fully-functional / unrestricted schema.

But again, what would stop a user from interrogating the app's bundle and discovering that the `https://api.service.com/graphql-anon` endpoint exists and using that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an aside: I would generally advocate having a separate schema and endpoint for your public API, for any number of reasons:

- **Clear documentation.** Sharing a schema means certain fields or arguments will be either inaccessible or will throw an error if used, and this may not be easily apparent when looking at GraphiQL/GraphQL Playground or introspecting the schema.
- **Cleaner code.** Your resolvers won't have nearly as much branching logic, which will make them easier to read and easier to test.
- **Differences under the hood.** There may be functionality (like caching or analytics) that you implement for your "internal" API that won't make sense for your public API (and may unnecessarily add on to the cost of maintaining the endpoint).
- **Rate limiting.** You will want to implement some kind of rate limiting for your public API. That's probably going to be easier to do if you have separate endpoints.

That said, obviously there's a cost associated with maintaining two separate APIs so this may not be a suitable solution in all cases.

Going back to the question at hand... Regardless of the above considerations, generally you would use token-based authentication to restrict access to all or some of your API, but you would not store this token as part of your app. A typical basic flow goes like this:

- The client calls some login endpoint with the user's credentials and gets back an authentication flow
- The token is temporarily persisted by the client and sent with every subsequent request to the API
- When the user logs out, the token is deleted

The server uses the token to establish the identity of the user, and this can then be made available to each GraphQL resolver function through the request's context. This allows you to effectively only return data for a specific field if the user is authenticated (or if her role allows access to that field). If the field is not accessible to the user, it can just return null or an empty array, depending on the type.

Of course, you could also have some small set of queries available to unauthenticated users. This approach lets you have varying levels of access depending on role (so an "admin" user might have access to more queries or fields than a "standard" user, who has more access than an unauthenticated user).

In the case of a public API, you can identify third-party clients using some combination of client tokens in a similar manner (maybe they don't have to login, but use a hash of a token and a secret that you assign to them on registration for example). If you have a shared schema, it's possible to support both kinds of authentication mechanisms. In this way, "third-party client" can just be another role that has an access to some subset of fields.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. If I were to go with a separate API for public access, do you have any suggestions / advice on how to protect the “internal” API from being discovered / abused? This was my concern with Option 2 above.

Comment: You would still want to implement authentication and limit access as described above. You can implement custom authentication headers and rate limiting to discourage abuse but I don't believe realistically you can have an API that's accessible via the Internet and limit access to just your clients.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. In my official UI I want anonymous users to be able to query for almost as much data as signed-in users can. So how would I go about detecting / rate limiting someone when you don’t *have to* signed in / create an auth token to use 90% of the app?

Comment: You may want to consider requiring a login, even if it's using SSO through a provider like Google or Facebook. Aside from that, you can have clients send some kind of unique identifier based on the device being used (there's libraries like `device-uuid` to do that sort of thing client side).

Comment: Maintain an internal profile for the client and/or session, which deems them a normal-human vs a bot-attempting-to-scrape. This could be done with a variety of tools like intermittent captcha-checks in the front-end, or observing/recording browsing patterns. In the end it's never 100% but can get you close.